# Barcode Scanner With Image capture in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, barcode-scanner

I have implemented barcode scanner in my xamarin application using xzing.net.mobile.forms component.which gives me bar code number.
but if i want to capture image also at same time of scanning .is there any other plug in available which give me image as well as bar code.
Any Help Appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What you have Tried ? Share your code so we can see what went wrong...

Comment: Do you mean something like: when successful scan a bar code,  take a pic of it and store both?

Answer (score 5):

I think you can use ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter (It should exists also for Xamarin Forms)

```
public static ImageSource QR(string data, int w, int h, int m) {
            var gen = new BarcodeWriter {
            Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
            Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions {
                Height = h,
                Width = w,
                Margin = m
            }
        };
        var bytes = gen.Write(data);
        return ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(bytes));
    }
```

Comment: thank you alessandro for your reply.but i dont want to create image from barcode. what i am trying to get is image click from camera.so is there any other plug in availbe in which it clicks image as wel as get barcode when scaning starts.?

Answer (score 0):

an other component for Barcode scan "Scandit Barcode Scanner SDK"

Comment: it does  not provide image capturing at scanning  feature.